# Did the marauders like Peter Pettigrew?

Tags: harry-potter, hogwarts

[Tgis answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/9455/25353) says that the marauders didn't like Peter. Is this true? Is there any canon proof of this, perhaps a JKR interview or something?

For me, Sirius and James were perhaps some of the most popular people in Hogwarts when they were Marauders and they really liked Remus, even if he wasn't one of the popular kids.

They were very rude, though, (with Snape, for example) and I don't imagine them hanging with Peter, helping him become an Animagus (which is pretty difficult) and let him be a part of the Marauders if he was a jerk and a looser.  I really hate Peter, but I always thought he must have been a pretty cool guy back at Hogwarts, funny and everything, otherwise Sirius and James would have bullied him, not let him be a part of the team.

Αre there any sources?

Comment: Technically, that answer says that they didn't *appreciate* him and that *he* felt like they didn't like him, which isn't quite the same as them not actually liking them. That said, there's at least one memory that Harry sees where Sirius is a bit mean to him.

Comment: In fact, the answer just made me thought. The point of the question was (like the title says) did the marauders like Peter? And if no, why was he allowed to stay with them and to be a part of the crew?

Comment: There's always a dopey one in every gang. Reference Goonies 'Chunk' and the other kid in Stand by Me. They were made fun of but generally liked and made up part of a group dynamic that was needed - the gopher/scapegoat/foil to the other stronger personalities.

Comment: If they didn't like Peter, why would they have kept him in their gang?  The question is not if they liked him; rather, it is why they liked the little rat.

Comment: Maybe they liked him, but he didn't recognize that due to low self-image.

Answer (score 6):

Peter Pettigrew, also known as Wormtail (nickname derived from his [animagus form](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Animagus?file=Scabbers_The_Rat.jpg)), was a good friend of James, Sirius, and Lupin. He was also [secret-keeper](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Peter_Pettigrew) for James and Lily when they were forced to go into hiding from Lord Voldemort, but betrayed them to save himself, resulting in the fulfillment of the [prophecy.](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Sybill_Trelawney%27s_first_prophecy)

Pettigrew was also described in DH in one of Snape's memories to be quieter than the rest of the group.

> In his youth, he [Pettigrew] latched onto James Potter and Sirius Black, more talented and popular students, idolizing them and living vicariously through their accomplishments, as well as joining them in bullying other students, such as Severus Snape, whom he would not have been likely to cross without James and Sirius to back him up. Due to the huge difference in terms of talent, bravery, and popularity, Peter was more of a hanger-on than an actual equal.
>   ([Harry Potter Wiki](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Peter_Pettigrew))

Pettigrew was very useful to the Marauders because he, in his animagus form of a rat, was able to paralyse the Whomping Willow to open the tunnel to the Shrieking Shack ([x](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Peter_Pettigrew)) where they would all go when Lupin transformed under the full moon.

No canonical evidence shows that the other Marauders particularly disliked Pettigrew, but similarly there is no evidence showing they liked him very much. One could easily infer that the group only kept him around because of his use when Lupin transformed. According to McGonagall, he wasn't a very competent student, but he does seem advanced in the Dark Arts:

> Despite Professor McGonagall claiming that Pettigrew was a barely competent student, and Voldemort later denoting him as a poor wizard, he showed a surprising amount of capability in certain situations. From what is known, Peter does not seem to be any less magically capable than the other three Marauders. In fact, he seems to be quite adept at using the Dark Arts; perhaps even the most capable of all four.
>   [(source)](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Peter_Pettigrew)

Perhaps that was the only reason the Marauders kept him around; perhaps it was Peter's idea in the first place to become Animagi when they didn't want to leave Lupin behind die to his situation, and perhaps Peter was the one who did all the research and taught them all how to transform.

There are countless possibilities as to why the Marauders accepted Pettigrew, because he did not at all seem popular in the books except for the fact that he was friends with James Potter, Sirius Black, and Remus Lupin.

Comment: "and perhaps Peter was the one who did all the research and taught them all how to transform" This is speculation. In fact I believe there's a phrase in PoA where actually had to help him - a lot! Other than that a good answer.

Comment: Pure personal speculation: I always saw their "dislike" of Peter as being in his own head. They liked him just fine, but his self-perception was flawed (perhaps due to depression or something else that can cause low self-esteem).