# When does Wormtail switch sides?

Tags: harry-potter, death-eaters

I've had a long drawn out debate with someone and we can't agree when Wormtail switches sides.

[The wiki](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Peter_Pettigrew) says:

> After graduating from Hogwarts, Pettigrew and his friends joined the Order of the Phoenix and fought against Lord Voldemort and the Death Eaters during the First Wizarding War. However, **at some point**, Pettigrew began working as a double agent for Voldemort, having come to the belief that nothing could be gained from opposing him. Despite being considered a low-ranking soldier for his coward.

I know that he betrayed Lily and James on the night they died but that doesn't say when he starts working for Voldemort.

Comment: Do you mean before or after the Potter's death?

Comment: related: [Why Did Peter Pettigrew Become a Death Eater?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/9433/why-did-peter-pettigrew-become-a-death-eater). Specifically, Steven Wood's answer goes into a possible chain of events leading to his allegiance change.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't think we can give a precise date, but there's at least one relevant statement.  In *Harry Potter and the Prisoner of Azkaban* chapter 19, Sirius accuses Peter with this statement, and he is probably right.

> ‘DON'T LIE!’ bellowed Black. ‘YOU'D BEEN PASSING INFORMATION TO HIM FOR A YEAR BEFORE LILY AND JAMES DIED! YOU WERE HIS SPY!’

Answer (score 5):

The books do not give us a date, nor do we have a clear indication of how long after they graduated was Harry born, or Voldemorts attack on the potters. A reasonable answer is at least a few months if not longer before the Potters were attacked, as when Sirius was explaining why they chose Peter as the secret keeper, it was because they knew there was a spy in the order and they had suspicions of Lupin.

Comment: They were 21 when they died, so 20 when he was born, and don't all Hogwarts students graduate at 18?

Comment: I've not read the last book recently (getting there though) but you can read their birth and death dates on their graves. Unless I'm mistaken, they were both 1960-1981.