# Are there any known wizards who 'went bad' that were in Gryffindor?

Tags: harry-potter

Hagrid states:

> there wasn’t one wizard that went bad that wasn’t in Slytherin

But I don’t think it’s true. Are there any known wizards who 'went bad' that were in Gryffindor?

I prefer answers from canon. Also I want to know them, and if they were significant to the HP story.

Comment: Related: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/116719/why-did-hagrid-say-that-all-bad-witches-and-wizards-are-from-slytherin (since my previous comment was deleted)

Answer (score 6):

## Yes, Peter Pettigrew was a Gryffindor and a Death Eater.

Peter Pettigrew was a Gryffindor who ‘went bad’ - Snape’s memories confirm conclusively that he was a Gryffindor, as Snape was watching the  Sorting ceremony and saw him join Gryffindor.

> “The roll call continued. Harry watched Lupin, Pettigrew and his father join Lily and Sirius at the Gryffindor table.” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows, Chapter 33 (The Prince’s Tale)*</sup></sub>

Though he’s looked down upon for his cowardice by the Dark Lord and Death Eaters, he’s a full member of the Death Eaters, including having a place in their circle and a Dark Mark.

> “Wormtail walked out of the circle to the place where Cedric’s body lay, and returned with Harry’s wand, which he thrust roughly into Harry’s hand without looking at him. Then Wormtail resumed his place in the circle of watching Death Eaters.” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire, Chapter 34 (Priori Incantatem)*</sup></sub>

Comment: Plus, everyone thought that Black was a dark wizard before the end of the 3rd book, and he was in Griffindor.